# How can I resolve Python TypeError: 'module' object is not callable?

Tags: python, import, module, callable

I'm trying to write a set of Python classes that would query a database to retrieve some values then construct a network graph. Problem is I get this error whenever I try to call the constructor for one of my classes
The relevant code is as follows

```
class NetworkConstructor:  
def __init__(self):
    self.nodes=dict()
    self.queryservice=QueryService()
    self.graph=networkx.Graph()
```

And the relevant bits from QueryService class is

```
def __init__(self):
    self.connect()

def connect(self):
    self.conn=MySQLdb.Connect(host="xxx", port=3306,user="xxx",passwd="xxx",db="xxx")
    self.cursor=self.conn.cursor()
```

And I have imported all required libraries as well

Comment: Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: Could you update the question with the whole stacktrace? :) Also, are the class' in the same file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your QueryService class is in a module with the same name. Try

```
self.queryservice=QueryService.QueryService()
```